# SharePoint lists: change the properties of existing rows

Tags: json, list, sharepoint

I have several existing lists in SharePoint. With Json, I'm able to restyle some of the default properties,  but I didn't succeed yet in restyling full rows.

The purpose is to decrease line height, in order to have more information on the screen. The zones to be decreased are indicated by red on the image:
[To be decreased zones of the rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL5uL.png)

I was able to change the padding and height of the individual cells within the json for the columns, but this didn't change the row height.

I'm doing something wrong on the rows; I couldn't relate any styling to a row. I expect something should go on the place of the question marks:

```
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/column-formatting.schema.json",
  <???>
  "style": {
    "padding": "0px",
    "height": "15px"
  }
}
```

Could someone provide an easy example?
(I did read other topics, but most of them created div's on the fly, which isn't the purpose here.)

Thanks in advance.